# How to use class->function() in fatfreeframework template

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I have a class as below.

```
class myClass {

    //Strip string
    function strip($str) {
        return $str;
    }
}
```

In my code, I call the template as below.

```
echo \Template::instance()->render('admin/settings.html');
```

Now how do I apply class function to a variable in the template? What I want to do is something like this.

```
{{ myClass->strip((@value['setting__Setting'])) }}
```

This does not actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use static function?

```
<?php
class myClass {

    //Strip string
    public static function strip($str) {
        return $str;
    }
}
```

Call static function in template:

```
{{ \myClass::strip((@value['setting__Setting'])) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually create an anonymous function that actually calls your class, so basically you'll be using your class method but in a nice way!

First, assign your class into a HIVE variable, you can do it like this anywhere in the class (`__construct` recommended)

```
$this->f3->set('_strip',function ($a){
    return $this->strip($a);
});
```

Now you can call that method in your templates like this,

```
{{ @_strip('Hello World') }}
```